# Upgrading base jail with iocage fails on FreeBSD/FreeNAS

Tags: freebsd, upgrade, jails

I have tried to upgrade a few 11.3 base jails to 11.4 on my FreeNAS server running FreeBSD 11.3. I used:

```
iocage upgrade -r 11.4-RELEASE my-jail-name
```

Some of the jails were failing with `etcupdate failed! Rolling back snapshot` message. When I tried running `etcupdate` manually, both inside the jail, and from the outside using `iocage exec` I got a further message: `Failed to build new tree.` What is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out the reason the `/usr/local/sbin/etcupdate` script was failing was because it was protecting some files from being deleted by setting a `chflags schg` system immutable flag, see line 213 of that script:

```
chflags -R noschg $1 >&3 2>&1 || return 1
```

Unfortunately, it was unable to clear that flag further on, and lines 265-266 were erring with `Operation not permitted`:

```
chflags -R noschg $1 >&3 2>&1
rm -rf $1 >&3 2>&1
```

This is because even though the jail had the necessary `allow_chflags` setting on, its `securelevel` was at the default value of `2` which allows for `schg` to be set, but it does *not* allow for it to be *unset.*

To fix this, I needed to change the jail's `securelevel` to `0` temporarily, making sure `allow_chflags` is on, then the `iocage upgrade` worked. After the upgrade I changed back the `securelevel` to the more secure, default value of `2`.

I am posting this here in case it helps somebody else.